# Is there a way to generate excel report in c# using interop excel with version indepent?

Tags: office-interop, com-interop, excel-interop

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and installed "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel V 15.0.4795.1000" using Nuget.
When I generating excel report it is working fine with "Microsoft Office 2013". But, getting error message with "Microsoft Office Home and Business 2019".

Error Message : Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC Exception : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

I assume that Interop Excel V 15 is not supporting with office 2019.

I used below code to create excel application.

```
using ExApp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
ExApp.Application xlApp = new ExApp.Application();
```

Later, I also tried with below code thinking that it will work with multiple versions of excel.

```
Type ExcelType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");
dynamic xlApp = Activator.CreateInstance(ExcelType);
```

Is there a way we can generate excel report in c# on any version of excel (2007 to 2019)?

At least, I need solution for "Microsoft Office Home and Business 2019".

Comment: I am not sure if I follow exactly what isn’t working. From my research, the _"Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel V 15.0.4795.1000" using Nuget_ is for Excel 2013. Therefore, it is not surprising to see the code fail on a machine running office 2019. Is there some reason you don’t use the “installed” Excel 2019 libraries?

Comment: Hi JohnG, Thanks for your reply. Creating excel application instance is not working if the machine has excel 2019 (code I mentioned in the above post).  Application is successfully running on my machine where i am using Excel 2010. When I installed in client machine, It is working perfectly on 2007, 2010,2013 and 2016. But, it is not working on a particular machine where user using "Microsoft Office Home and Business 2019". Please let me know if you need additional information. Thanks

Comment: I could be mistaken, however, from my understanding, if you compile code that uses an Interop Library like Excel Version 15 (as the code appears to use), then, if the target machine that runs the code does NOT have this same Excel Version 15, then a crash is likely. I have office 2019 and from what I can see Excel 2019 uses Version 16. I assume you could put the needed libraries on the target machine, or take the code to the target machine and remove the reference to the Excel 15 and set the reference to Version 16. You may need to alter the code to fit the library.

Comment: Again, I am not 100% positive about this, however, I am confident that when using office interop the version the code uses and the version on the target machine MUST match. I am guessing that you may be able to avoid this by using another library, like OpenXML or EPPlus. Unfortunately, this will most likely require numerous code changes to the existing code.

Comment: Hi JohnG, Thanks for your reply. I was in an impression that excel 2019 uses Version 15. Do you have any idea where I can down load Interop.Excel V16?. As you mentioned I can't use other libraries like OpenXML at this state due to lot of code changes required.

Comment: In checking the versions that I use running office 2019 pro, I get different version numbers. Looking at the “file” info states its version 15 for 2013, however the reference in VS states it is version 16. So obviously I am missing something as I could not find the 2019 v 16 assembly. Again, I suggest you copy the 2013 Excel assembly to the machine with 2019 and remove/add the Excel reference in the code to point to the copy you got from the 2013 assembly. This assumes VS is on that machine… OR …

Comment: Install VS on the machine that is running Excel 2019 (if it is not there). Then copy the current code solution to the 2019 machine, load the solution, then “remove” the current reference to Excel and Office. The code is obviously going to show a bunch of errors since the reference is gone.

Comment: Then right click on “Reference” in the solution explorer and select “Add Reference.” A window will open to add a reference from different choices… click on the “COM” section on the left. Then scroll down to “Microsoft Excel XX.X Object Library.” This “should” be the version of Excel that is installed on that machine. I assume it would be “Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library.” Whatever version it is, choose it.

Comment: Once this is done, “most” of the errors “should” go away, however, it is possible that some methods may need to be changed to fit the newer calls. In my experience these changes have been minimal and straight forward. Once the errors have been addressed, compiling the code and running it should work with whatever version of Excel is on that machine, in this case 2019. Bear in mind that you want to keep the old code since it will be needed for the other versions of Excel. This new version will only work with 2019.